# La ilaha il al Allah Umar RasulAllah?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

Salam

I've read hadiths that state that Umar al Khattab (ra) was considered by God to be the prophet after Muhammad (PBUH).

I'm a monotheistic jewish woman and I believe in the prophethood of Umar (PBUH)

Is Omarism a sunni branch of Islam?

Comment: What makes you think this way? Nowhere does the hadiths state that Umar al Khattab (ra) was considered by God to be the prophet after Muhammad (PBUH)

Comment: Why do you believe in the prophethood of Umar anyway?

Comment: Please share your source of the claimed hadith. There's no hadith I know of pretending this nor will you find any sunni Muslim claiming to regard 'Umar a prophet. I only know of some aggressive shi' a preachers pretending that 'Aishah and ibn' Umar changed Islam.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably confusing it with the hadith in which the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said "If there was to be a prophet after me, it would be Umar ibn Al Khattab (ra)." He never said there was a prophet after him. Not Umar, not Abu Bakr, not Ali, or anyone else. He's the final messenger and the seal of all messengers before him. He is Muhammad Rasulallah.

Answer (score 0):

Sister

None of the authentic hadith say this(Omar(ra) us a prophet) . You might have read a fabrication(false hadith).

Because Quran is clear about this, Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) was the last prophet of Allah(God).

> **Muḥammad is not the father of any of your men,1 but is the Messenger of Allah and the seal of the prophets. And Allah has ˹perfect˺ knowledge of all things**.

Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran 33:40

> **Muḥammad is not the father of [any] one of your men, but [he is] the Messenger of Allah and seal [i.e., last] of the prophets. And ever is Allah, of all things, Knowing**.

Saheeh International 33:40

So these verse means that prophet MUHAMMAD(PBUH) is the last prophet.

Comment: Kindly see the user's previous questions on this site and on Judaism and Christanity SE, this is not a serious question.

Comment: Ok, but why downvote